# Could they have avoided it?

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

> Weird undiscovered disease slams twins equally.

*Did they catch it in Lyon, Turin or Barcelona?*

Hint

> They were warned about what was going to happen: they had read it somewhere beforehand.

Hint 2

> Each word is a loose "synonym" for another one. All the "synonyms" belong to a certain well-known group. One of the proposed answers also follows that pattern.

Comment: @RewanDemontay perhaps it is an [tag:enigmatic-puzzle]? It should probably have the tag, then.

Comment: Edited question to make it a bit clearer

Comment: The word cadence sounds like a mnemonic device

Comment: Was the original puzzle solvable, and the edit just points towards the correct direction? Or should we completely ignore the original post?

Comment: I think it was as solvable as it is now. The question can only be answered if you found the underlying pattern in the sencence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe they caught it in

> Lyon

because

> "Disease", "slams", "twins", and "equally" correspond to Cancer, Aries (the Ram), Gemini, and Libra respectively: between the three cities, Lyon would correspond to Leo (or the Lion).

I can't quite make out

> the first two words; I suspect "undiscovered" refers to Virgo, but "weird" still has me stumped.

Comment: Possibly rot13(JRVEQ = PNCEVPVBHF = PNCEVPBEA)?

Comment: Great ! rot13(Ivetb nf va ivetva nf va haqvfpbirerq. Sbe gur "jrveq" cneg, V jnf tbvat sbe SVFUL ohg vg jnf gur zbfg sne-srgpurq bar ;))

Answer (score 2):

I believe that they caught it in:

> Barcelona, because: "DISEASE" anagrams to "SEASIDE" (Barcelona is the only option with a seaside), and potentially, taking most of "BARCELONA", we can get "BALANCE".Not sure if this is correct, nor full enough.

Comment: No anagrams involved. Strangely enough, "BALANCE" is an important word for this puzzle though !